# SharePoint 2013 , App, Configuration and Deployment : Either 401 UNAUTHORIZED page or Incorrect Link After SharePoint 2013 App Deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I'm new to SharePoint.
I have a problem during post-deployment of SharePoint Apps.
the following points are the settings of my App Domain's configuration :

I carefully followed the next 3 links :

`http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236%28v=office.15%29`

`http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx`

`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923%28v=office.15%29.aspx`

I can deploy, install and trust the app but i can't open it after that:

1/ For `Sharepoint-Hosted Apps`:  when I click on my App in My Sharepoint Site, I get a Blank page which contains as error :

> Make sure the web address `http://apps-184e03e3ea024f.sp.local/sites/TrainingSiteCollection/SPHostedApp_SimpleDateApp3/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapp%2Fsites%2FTrainingSiteCollection&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4420%2E1017&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapps%2D184e03e3ea024f%2Esp%2Elocal%2Fsites%2FTrainingSiteCollection%2FSPHostedApp%5FSimpleDateApp3` is correct

2/ For `Provider Hosted Apps` and  `SharePoint Store apps` :

An authorization Popup is displayed in order to enter my credentials but I cannot Authenticate to the app ( I'm sure that Authentication parameters are correct ) but after 3 tries , 401 UNAUTHORIZED Page is displayed.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `LoopBackCheck` behavior ...
To disable this, just add `DisableLoopbackCheck` `DWORD` to registry with value of `1`.

And to do so, you need to go to HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa and add the `DWORd` there.

Best Regards.